# 9-patch Android 4 issue, works Android 2.3

Tags: android, nine-patch

I created a 9-patch for a button "Day" in the images link below that works as expected on my Android 2.3 phone.  When I run for Android 4 Tablet, it does not work.  Not sure if I need to tweak the xml or issue in how the 9-patch is created.  Also, I only have the drawable in the "drawable-hdpi" folder in Eclipse.  Any help is appreciated!

```
 <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonTabSummary"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/more_cap_en"
            android:textSize="9sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonTabDay"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/day_cap"
            android:textSize="9sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonTabWeek"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/more_cap"
            android:textSize="9sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonTabShare"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/more"
            android:textSize="9sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonTabMore"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/more"
            android:textSize="9sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

[9-patch creater top screen.  Android 2.3 bottom left, Android 4 bottom right (not displaying correctly](http://bodybuildingdietapp.com/printScreen.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put it in the drawable folder instead of drawable-hdpi. Looks like your tablet doesn't have hdpi resolution, so maybe it cannot find the image.